# Use cases of the Signleton pattern

Tags: design-patterns, singleton

I am doing a test, and I am confused on the below question.

Which type of application would benefit from using the Singleton pattern?

- A.   An application that interacts with external systems in serial
  fashion.
- B.   An application that interacts with external systems in parallel
  fashion.
- C.   A clustered application that can support 200 concurrent users.
- D.   An application that requires remote monitoring capabilities

There are some tests that the right answer is A and other tests that the answer is D. What is the correct answer?

Comment: Would have to refer to the material the question is based on. Seems like a rather subjective question to me.

Comment: Trick question. Singleton is an anti-pattern. Don't use it.

Comment: Idiotic question. It depends on the implementation of the app. It might be a valid pattern or not.

Comment: @Jack which answer do you think is correct, and why?

Answer (score 0):

What about (E) - a small project which is not going to be heavily tested?

Singleton is an anti-pattern. You should not use it in your system as it pollutes your global state, is more complex and less useful. You don't want to be coupled to a singleton. Moreover, using it in a multi-threaded environment would lead to a disaster. Imagine you have several tests which each changes the singleton's instance. Now imagine the tests are concurring.

Eliminate the use of the Singleton pattern in your code-base and start considering a better design. I would suggest taking advantage of the dependency inversion principle and using a dependency container instead.

Answer (score 0):

A is correct answer
Reason : You can model an external system as a singleton class.